# How can I leftalign each column of a table?

Tags: latex

I want to describe a number of variables in an equation and format it in a certain way. I don't know how to do that.

I have tried using the `\begin{table}` environment together with `\begin{flushleft}` and `\begin{tabular}`. 
Also, I tried using `\begin{align*}` and `\begin{flalign*}`.

```
\begin{flalign*}
    &C_R&\text{CO\textsubscript{2}-Masse pro Luftvolumen im Büro}&[\frac{g}{m^3}]\\
    &C_{Amb}&\text{CO\textsubscript{2}-Masse pro Luftvolumen in der Umgebung}&[\frac{g}{m^3}]\\
    &C_{Corr}&\text{CO\textsubscript{2}-Masse pro Luftvolumen im Flur}&[\frac{g}{m^3}]\\
    &C_{ProdPP}&\text{CO\textsubscript{2}-Masse-Produktion pro Luftvolumen pro Person}&[\frac{g}{min}]\\
    &\dot{m}_{airx}&\text{Luftmassenstrom vom Büro in die Umgebung und benachbarte Räume}&[\frac{kg}{min}]\\
    &\dot{m}_{Amb}&\text{Luftmassenstrom von der Umgebung in das Büro}&[\frac{kg}{min}]\\
    &\dot{m}_{Corr}&\text{Luftmassenstrom vom Flur in das Büro}&[\frac{kg}{min}]\\
    &\rho_{air}&\text{Dichte der Luft}&[\frac{kg}{m^3}]\\
    &V_{office}&\text{Volumen des Büros}&[m^3]\\
    &\Delta t&\text{Zeitschritt}&[min]\\
    &n_{OCC,i}&\text{Anzahl der anwesenden Personen}&[-]\\
\end{flalign*}
```

```
\begin{table}
\begin{flushleft}
    \begin{tabular}{c c c}
        $C_R$&\text{CO\textsubscript{2}-Masse pro Luftvolumen im Büro}&[$\frac{g}{m^3}$]\\
        $C_{Amb}$&\text{CO\textsubscript{2}-Masse pro Luftvolumen in der Umgebung}&[$\frac{g}{m^3}$]\\
        $C_{Corr}$&\text{CO\textsubscript{2}-Masse pro Luftvolumen im Flur}&[$\frac{g}{m^3}$]\\
        $C_{ProdPP}$&\text{CO\textsubscript{2}-Masse-Produktion pro Luftvolumen pro Person}&[$\frac{g}{min}$]\\
        $\dot{m}_{airx}$&\text{Luftmassenstrom vom Büro in die Umgebung und benachbarte Räume}&[$\frac{kg}{min}$]\\
        $\dot{m}_{Amb}$&\text{Luftmassenstrom von der Umgebung in das Büro}&[$\frac{kg}{min}$]\\
        $\dot{m}_{Corr}$&\text{Luftmassenstrom vom Flur in das Büro}&[$\frac{kg}{min}$]\\
        $\rho_{air}$&\text{Dichte der Luft}&[$\frac{kg}{m^3}$]\\
        $V_{office}$&\text{Volumen des Büros}&[$m^3$]\\
        $\Delta t$&\text{Zeitschritt}&[$min$]\\
%       $n_{OCC,i}$&\text{Anzahl der anwesenden Personen}&[$-$]\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}
\end{table}
```

This is the current result I get:

[image]

Here, the middle column is right-aligned.
But I want each column to be aligned to the left.

Answer (score 1):

If the columns should be left aligned, I suggest to simply use `l` columns instead of `c` columns:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}
%\begin{flushleft}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
        $C_R$&\text{CO\textsubscript{2}-Masse pro Luftvolumen im Büro}&[$\frac{g}{m^3}$]\\
        $C_{Amb}$&\text{CO\textsubscript{2}-Masse pro Luftvolumen in der Umgebung}&[$\frac{g}{m^3}$]\\
        $C_{Corr}$&\text{CO\textsubscript{2}-Masse pro Luftvolumen im Flur}&[$\frac{g}{m^3}$]\\
        $C_{ProdPP}$&\text{CO\textsubscript{2}-Masse-Produktion pro Luftvolumen pro Person}&[$\frac{g}{min}$]\\
        $\dot{m}_{airx}$&\text{Luftmassenstrom vom Büro in die Umgebung und benachbarte Räume}&[$\frac{kg}{min}$]\\
        $\dot{m}_{Amb}$&\text{Luftmassenstrom von der Umgebung in das Büro}&[$\frac{kg}{min}$]\\
        $\dot{m}_{Corr}$&\text{Luftmassenstrom vom Flur in das Büro}&[$\frac{kg}{min}$]\\
        $\rho_{air}$&\text{Dichte der Luft}&[$\frac{kg}{m^3}$]\\
        $V_{office}$&\text{Volumen des Büros}&[$m^3$]\\
        $\Delta t$&\text{Zeitschritt}&[$min$]\\
%       $n_{OCC,i}$&\text{Anzahl der anwesenden Personen}&[$-$]\\
    \end{tabular}
%\end{flushleft}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(unrelated to the problem: units should be set upright and math mode should not be used for multi-letter words like `min`, `office` etc. It might be a good idea to have look at the `siunitx` package to make it easier to typeset units correctly)

Comment: thanks! very simple and helpful. btw, do you know why the question was put on hold as off-topic? Latex is a topic in stackoverflow after all..

Comment: @naraghi I guess it is on hold because the whole system is utterly broken. In my opinion it should be migrated to tex.stackexchange.com, but migration never happens. From over 100 posts I flagged for migration, only a single one was actually migrated, all other posts are randomly closed or ignored....